# Question based on average and age

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> On 1st January, 2000 the average age of a family of 6 people was A years. After 5 years a child was born in the family and one year after that the average age was again found to be ‘A’ years. What is the value of ‘A’? (Assume that there are no other deaths and births.)

What I did:- Total sum of ages of 6 family members:- 6A
Total sum after 5 years:-
6(A+5)=6A+30
Now what to do after this?

Comment: Hint:  The baby is is one year old at the last measure, and the other members average $A+6$.  so the total age of the family is $6(A+6)+1$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$S=\sum_{i=1}^6a_i .$$

We have

$$\frac {S}{6}=A=\frac {S+6\times 6+1}{7}$$

thus
$$S=222$$
and
$$A=37$$